# Cumulative Sum in R based on Date and other conditions using data.table

Tags: r, date, data.table, conditional-statements, cumulative-sum

I have some football data (2020/2021 Serie A), and I would like to compute the number of games each team played over the last n days (lets say to simplify over the last 30 days). Conditions are thus the team, the day the game is played (strictly smaller than) and that same day - 30 (greater or equal to).

I would like to know what is the best way to do that using data.table (alone), and more important, the logic behind the code. I woudl go for a loop over the teams and dates, but I think it is cumbersome and I am sure there is a way to have it done in one single row.

A sample is given below, with the result I would expect (day and date might seem misleading, because some games were postponed, but that is not important. Data is classified by date). Thank you very much.

| Code | Team | Date | Day | Date - 30d | Games played over the last 30 days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TORATA | Atalanta | 2020-09-26 | 2 | 2020-08-27 | NA |
| LAZATA | Atalanta | 2020-09-30 | 1 | 2020-08-31 | 1 |
| ATACAG | Atalanta | 2020-10-04 | 3 | 2020-09-04 | 2 |
| NAPATA | Atalanta | 2020-10-17 | 4 | 2020-09-17 | 3 |
| ATASAM | Atalanta | 2020-10-24 | 5 | 2020-09-24 | 4 |
| CROATA | Atalanta | 2020-10-31 | 6 | 2020-10-01 | 3 |
| ATAINT | Atalanta | 2020-11-08 | 7 | 2020-10-09 | 3 |

Comment: Not clear how to calculate the last column.

Comment: That is a counter on the number of games which occured between Date-30d and Date. Basically, it counts the number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one implementation, just `data.table` and base R:

```r
dat[, z := sapply(Date, function(z) sum(between(z - Date, 0.1, 30)))]
dat
#      Code     Team       Date   Day Date...30d Games.played.over.the.last.30.days     z
#    <char>   <char>     <Date> <int>     <Date>                              <int> <int>
# 1: TORATA Atalanta 2020-09-26     2 2020-08-27                                 NA     0
# 2: LAZATA Atalanta 2020-09-30     1 2020-08-31                                  1     1
# 3: ATACAG Atalanta 2020-10-04     3 2020-09-04                                  2     2
# 4: NAPATA Atalanta 2020-10-17     4 2020-09-17                                  3     3
# 5: ATASAM Atalanta 2020-10-24     5 2020-09-24                                  4     4
# 6: CROATA Atalanta 2020-10-31     6 2020-10-01                                  3     3
# 7: ATAINT Atalanta 2020-11-08     7 2020-10-09                                  3     3
```

In this case, for each `Date` value, we count how many of the dates are within 30 days of it.

If you need the `NA` in place of a `0`, then you can add on `dat[z < 1, z := NA]` or similar.

---

Data:

```r
library(data.table)
dat <- structure(list(Code = c("TORATA", "LAZATA", "ATACAG", "NAPATA", "ATASAM", "CROATA", "ATAINT"), Team = c("Atalanta", "Atalanta", "Atalanta", "Atalanta", "Atalanta", "Atalanta", "Atalanta"), Date = structure(c(18531, 18535, 18539, 18552, 18559, 18566, 18574), class = "Date"), Day = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), Date...30d = structure(c(18501, 18505, 18509, 18522, 18529, 18536, 18544), class = "Date"), Games.played.over.the.last.30.days = c(NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))
setDT(dat)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The one using the library "runner' was also fine, but yours is clean data.table and base, which I prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`runner`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/runner/vignettes/apply_any_r_function.html) in combination with `data.table` to calculate a running `Date` window count:

```
library(data.table)
library(runner)

setDT(data)

data[,Date:=as.Date(Date,'%Y-%m-%d')]

data[,N:=runner::runner(
                        x = Date, 
                        k = 30, # 30-days window
                        lag = 1,
                        idx = Date,
                        f = length)
    ,by=Team][]

     Code     Team       Date Day    Date30d Games30days N
1: TORATA Atalanta 2020-09-26   2 2020-08-27          NA 0
2: LAZATA Atalanta 2020-09-30   1 2020-08-31           1 1
3: ATACAG Atalanta 2020-10-04   3 2020-09-04           2 2
4: NAPATA Atalanta 2020-10-17   4 2020-09-17           3 3
5: ATASAM Atalanta 2020-10-24   5 2020-09-24           4 4
6: CROATA Atalanta 2020-10-31   6 2020-10-01           3 3
7: ATAINT Atalanta 2020-11-08   7 2020-10-09           3 3
```

Data:

```
data <- read.table(text='
Code    Team    Date    Day     Date30d     Games30days
TORATA  Atalanta    2020-09-26  2   2020-08-27  NA
LAZATA  Atalanta    2020-09-30  1   2020-08-31  1
ATACAG  Atalanta    2020-10-04  3   2020-09-04  2
NAPATA  Atalanta    2020-10-17  4   2020-09-17  3
ATASAM  Atalanta    2020-10-24  5   2020-09-24  4
CROATA  Atalanta    2020-10-31  6   2020-10-01  3
ATAINT  Atalanta    2020-11-08  7   2020-10-09  3',header=T)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still I have a few questions. after looking at the "runner"'s webpage, I understand that x is the data (here  a column vector data$Date), and that it shows the length of the vector based on the condition. Correct? Now they say, one can use any function. Let's say I would have one more column (flag) indicating if the team won the game or not (1 == victory, 0 something else), I understand I could use cumsum over that column to count the number of victories over a time interval. I am still missing something as my tests are all wrong. Can be "x" a 2 columns set?

Comment: this should work : `data[,wincount:=runner::runner(x = winflag,  k = 30,   lag = 1,  idx = Date,  f = sum),by=Team][]`

Answer (score 0):

You can get this with one line of code, using a non-equi join of the table onto itself.

Let's say `fb` is your input data (without the `Games30days` column). Like this:

```
     Code     Team       Date Day Date - 30d
1: TORATA Atalanta 2020-09-26   2 2020-08-27
2: LAZATA Atalanta 2020-09-30   1 2020-08-31
3: ATACAG Atalanta 2020-10-04   3 2020-09-04
4: NAPATA Atalanta 2020-10-17   4 2020-09-17
5: ATASAM Atalanta 2020-10-24   5 2020-09-24
6: CROATA Atalanta 2020-10-31   6 2020-10-01
7: ATAINT Atalanta 2020-11-08   7 2020-10-09
```

Then, just do a join on `Team=Team`, `Date<Date`, and `Date>Date - 30d`, like this:

```
games_played = fb[fb,on=.(Team = Team, Date<Date, Date>`Date - 30d`), nomatch=0][,.("Games30" =  .N), .(Date,Team)]
```

which returns

```
         Date     Team Games30
1: 2020-09-30 Atalanta       1
2: 2020-10-04 Atalanta       2
3: 2020-10-17 Atalanta       3
4: 2020-10-24 Atalanta       4
5: 2020-10-31 Atalanta       3
6: 2020-11-08 Atalanta       3
```

That result can easily be joined back to the original, to get all the columns, like this:

```
games_played[fb, on=.(Team, Date)]
```